# Can't get my array to hold more than one item at a time in shell

Tags: bash, shell, unix

Having an issue where my script won't iterate through my array and wont display correctly

```
#!/bin/bash
mispelledWords=$(cat $1|aspell list)
ARRAY=( $mispelledWords )

for((i=0; i<${#ARRAY[@]}; i++))
        do

        echo "'${ARRAY[i]}' is mispelled. Press 'Enter' to keep" 

        read -p 'this spelling, or type a correction here:' UserWord


        if [[ $UserWord == "" ]]; then

        echo ${ARRAY[i]} >> .memory
else 
        UserWordsArray[i]=$UserWord
        mispelledArray[i]=${ARRAY[i]}
        echo $mispelledArray[i]
        fi
done
echo    "MISPELLED:                     CORRECTIONS"

for ((i=0; i<${#UserWord[@]}; i++))
do
        echo "${mispelledArray[i]}                              ${UserWordsArray[i]}"
done
```

At the point where the array is supposed to be iterating through in the for loop, it only stores one value and when trying to display it in the else statement

```
echo $mispelledArray[i]
```

It only displays one of the values passed into the program through another textfile. 
Any help would be extremely helpful

Comment: Replace `echo $mispelledArray[i]` with `echo "${mispelledArray[i]}"`.

Comment: Awesome that fixed it but it is still not displaying in the lower for loop

Comment: Nevermind I fixed it thanks!